# Rails form not saving data with strong_params set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, parameters, controller

I have the following form in my rails test_app:

```
<%= form_for([@customer, @job]) do |f| %>
  <% if @job.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@job.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this job from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @job.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :box_count %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :box_count %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :install_date %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :install_date %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the create method in the jobs controller:

```
def create
 @job = Job.new(job_params)
 @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @job.save
    format.html { redirect_to customer_path(@customer), notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @job }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

And here are the job_params in the jobs controller:

```
def job_params
  params.require(:job).permit(:box_count, :install_date)
  params.permit(:customer_id)
end
```

Does anyone know why :box_count and :install_date do not write to the DB?

---

Added params from the create action:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"i9w0nH16NG491Aa/pbG979VntnRjUGGlhvqIahJViEE=", "job"=>{"box_count"=>"5", "install_date"=>"101014"}, "commit"=>"Create Job", "customer_id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: Ruby methods will return the last line.  So It'll return the `params.permit(:customer_id)` line

Comment: @japed even when moving :box_count and :install_date to the last line it still will not write to the DB.

Comment: @DustinJames show us your `params` coming to your `create` action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an association between Job & Customer. So you are doing it wrong my friend. Do this in this way:

```
Customer Modal

  has_many :jobs

Job Modal

  belongs_to :customer
```

Than do this:

```
def create
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
  @job = @customer.jobs.build(job_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @job.save
      format.html { redirect_to customer_path(@customer), notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @job }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And here are the job_params in the jobs controller:

```
def job_params
  params.require(:job).permit(:box_count, :install_date, :customer_id)      
end
```

Hope this will help.Thanks

Comment: That worked!  Odd thing about this is yesterday I had trouble with putting :customer_id in the first line of params, and it worked when I separated it.